# I want to use wget with variable for parameter

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, wget

I'am using google colaboratory and it gives me error messages

`File "<ipython-input-1-41d5736708c2>", line 14 wget --no-check-certificate foo -O bar ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

this is my code

```
foo = 'https://example.com'
bar = '/tmp/' + foo.rsplit('/')[-1]
wget --no-check-certificate foo -O bar
```

I was read entire tutorial videos, but everyone is using `wget https://example.com` instead of `wget (variable)`
is it possible to using wget with defined variable ?

Comment: ``Format your error messages with `message` so it can preserve line breaks.``

Comment: hi, thanks for advice

Comment: `When accessing variables in Bash, add dollar signs before their names. wget --no-check-certificate foo -O bar becomes wget --no-check-certificate $foo -O $bar`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interpolate the variables for the command with:

```
!wget --no-check-certificate {foo} -O {bar}
```